# WPF DockPanel MinHeight usage

Tags: wpf, dockpanel

How does `DockPanel` determine the `Height` of the bottom section?
If an explicit `Height` property is provided that will be used.
If `Height` is not provided but there is `MinHeight` and `MaxHeight` it seems to drop to `MinHeight` all the time, like this:

```
<DockPanel>

    <Button Name="btn" 
            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
            MinHeight="80" 
            MaxHeight="160"
            Content="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=ActualHeight}"
            />

    <Button Content="Center"/>

</DockPanel>
```

I used binding to show the `ActualHeight` as Button Content.

[image: Defaults to 80]

But not always! When I use a `ScrollViewer` as bottom component, it seems to use an intermediate value (33) between `MinHeight` (20) and `MaxHeight` (160).

```
<DockPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Name="sv" 
                  DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                  MinHeight="20" 
                  MaxHeight="160">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=sv, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Button Content="Center"/>

</DockPanel>
```

The surprising fact here is that it seems to use a more complex sizing algorithm than just looking at the `Height`/`MinHeight` of the component.
Maybe it's looking at the component type too, so for a `ScrollViewer` it's taking in account the content extent too. 
`DockPanel` docs don't go very in deep with an explanation of the default algorithm.
Where can I find a complete description?
Is the source code of those WPF standard controls available?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not so terribly mysterious.  What is fooling you is what fooled me for a long time.  It would seem that a declarative language would not be order dependent...oh but it is!

If you reverse the order of controls in your first example you find that the button will now be at maximum height instead of minimum.

If you reverse the order of controls in your second example you find that the scroll viewer will now be at maximum height centered in the view and the button will be docked to the left.

The reason the scrollview in your second example is height 33?  Well that is a result of the minimum sizes of component elements.  If you look at the Live Visual Tree you see that the scroll bar has 3 vertical elements: 2 repeater buttons and a track in a border.  The minimum sizes of each of these is 16, 16, 0, 1 which add up to 33.

Source code will not help you very much.  Once you figure out the layout mechanisms, their behavior will no longer seem complex.  Instead you will discover them to be crude and naive...all the better to anticipate the result.

To really delve into the standard controls you need the styles and templates which you can find at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates

Comment: "if you reverse the order"=>wrong: this is the effect of LastChildFill that defaults to true. Set this DockPanel prop. to false and even reversing the order the height will stay 33. Why height is 33=>what you say is interesting, but this means that there is a hidden MinHeight that is taken into account with precedence over the explicitly MinHeight set. And there is something strange with this explanation: when once reached the MinHeight, if you reduce the window height it should start clipping it, instead it still shrinks the heigth till 20! 33 Seems more like a preferred height!

Comment: There is no "hidden" min height.  The minimum rendered height of the button is a result of the arrow icons.  Also I am absolutely right about order dependency.  Try a window with 10 controls and tell me that order does not matter!  Again the layout is not rocket science.  You initially gave it a range between 20 and 160 and the control took 33 because that is what it took to render the scroll buttons.  When you forced it to take less that 33 then, sure, it started clipping.